# Having a trouble while application deployment- "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Alert->alerts'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper mapped class Alert->alerts, expression 'Slice' failed to locate a name ('Slice'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'superset.models.alerts.Alert'> class after both dependent classes have been defined. How to resolve this issue?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 07:12:15] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2021 07:12:15] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
ERROR:superset.app:Failed to create app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/superset/app.py", line 62, in create_app
    app_initializer.init_app()
  File "/app/superset/app.py", line 552, in init_app
    self.init_app_in_ctx()
  File "/app/superset/app.py", line 521, in init_app_in_ctx
    self.configure_fab()
  File "/app/superset/app.py", line 592, in configure_fab
    appbuilder.init_app(self.flask_app, db.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 202, in init_app
    self.sm = self.security_manager_class(self)
  File "/app/superset/custom_apis/base/custom_main.py", line 29, in __init__
    super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 55, in __init__
    user_datamodel = SQLAInterface(self.user_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/interface.py", line 62, in __init__
    for prop in sa.orm.class_mapper(obj).iterate_properties:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 451, in class_mapper
    mapper = _inspect_mapped_class(class_, configure=configure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 430, in _inspect_mapped_class
    mapper._configure_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1352, in _configure_all
    configure_mappers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3295, in configure_mappers
    raise e
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Alert->alerts'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper mapped class Alert->alerts, expression 'Slice' failed to locate a name ('Slice'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'superset.models.alerts.Alert'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Alert-Model code structure:

```
class Alert(Model, AuditMixinNullable):

    """Schedules for emailing slices / dashboards"""

    __tablename__ = "alerts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String(150), nullable=False)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True, index=True)
    # TODO(bkyryliuk): enforce minimal supported frequency
    crontab = Column(String(50), nullable=False)

    alert_type = Column(String(50))
    owners = relationship(security_manager.user_model, secondary=alert_owner)
    recipients = Column(Text)
    slack_channel = Column(Text)

    # TODO(bkyryliuk): implement log_retention
    log_retention = Column(Integer, default=90)
    grace_period = Column(Integer, default=60 * 60 * 24)

    slice_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("slices.id"))
    slice = relationship("Slice", backref="alerts", foreign_keys=[slice_id])

    dashboard_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("dashboards.id"))
    dashboard = relationship("Dashboard", backref="alert", foreign_keys=[dashboard_id])

    last_eval_dttm = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_state = Column(String(10))

    # Observation related columns
    sql = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

Slice model :

```
class Slice(
    Model, AuditMixinNullable, ImportExportMixin
):  # pylint: disable=too-many-public-methods

    """A slice is essentially a report or a view on data"""

    __tablename__ = "slices"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    slice_name = Column(String(250))
    datasource_id = Column(Integer)
    datasource_type = Column(String(200))
    datasource_name = Column(String(2000))
    viz_type = Column(String(250))
    params = Column(Text)
    description = Column(Text)
    cache_timeout = Column(Integer)
    perm = Column(String(1000))
    schema_perm = Column(String(1000))
    owners = relationship(security_manager.user_model, secondary=slice_user)
    table = relationship(
        "SqlaTable",
        foreign_keys=[datasource_id],
        primaryjoin="and_(Slice.datasource_id == SqlaTable.id, "
        "Slice.datasource_type == 'table')",
        remote_side="SqlaTable.id",
        lazy="subquery",
    )

    token = ""

    export_fields = [
        "slice_name",
        "datasource_type",
        "datasource_name",
        "viz_type",
        "params",
        "cache_timeout",
    ]
    export_parent = "table"
```

**SUPERSET-VERSION:** 0.38.0

Comment: Please add the related models file (containing Alert and Slice) Please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.